# Approximating Normal Distribution by adding Random Numbers

Tags: random, probability, normal-distribution

I would like to generate some random numbers which are normally distributed. It’s not mission critical, so a simple algorithm will suffice. I would then like to supply my own mean and standard deviation.

From what I have been able to read, according to the Central Limit Theorem, I should be able to approximate normally distributed random numbers by adding random numbers together.

For example:

```
rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()
```

where `rand()` results in an evenly distributed random number from 0 to 1
is a reasonable approximation. (I am aware that technically it’s `0 ≤ rand() < 1`).

The expected mean is `6*0.5` so I get to the desired mean with something like this:

```
(rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()-3) + mean
```

but what would the standard deviation be?

Once I know that, would setting an arbitrary standard deviation simply be a matter of multiplying?

**Update**

Experimentally, I have found that

```
(rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()+rand()-3)*sqrt(2)*sd+mean
```

gives me a set of data with the desired standard deviation and mean. I have tested this out in a database (PostgreSQL) with a 10 million rows, using the `stddev()` and `avg()` aggregate functions, and typical results are close to within 2 decimal places which isn’t too bad.

I have no idea why `sqrt(2)` is involved …

**Solution**

OK, thanks to Severin Pappadeux below, I have an answer.

I can generate a reasonable result with:

```
(rand() + … + rand() - n/2) / sqrt(n/12) * sd + mean
```

where `n` is the number of `rand()` calls I am prepared to make.

Comment: Please do not do this.  The central limit theorem is an asymptotic result, and 6 != infinity.  You will be unable to generate anything with a magnitude larger than 3. With a standard deviation of sqrt(2) that is 2.12 std deviations, which will *a priori* exclude 3.4% of the possible values, and distort the probabilities of the generated values accordingly.  It's also computationally more expensive than the exact techniques which are readily available.  See [Marsaglia's polar method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) as an example of a mathematically correct approach.

Comment: @pjs Marsaglia or Box-Muller might work but they require log() and/or trigonometric functions which are not available in sql. While summing 6 U(0,1) might be a bit low to my taste, sum of 12 could be an ok for simple N(0,1) sampling solution

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux [this](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-functions/ln.php) would seem to contradict that.

Comment: @pjs that's good - but it used to not to have log() and similar functions. And it is clearly vendor specific extensions, they're even named differently

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks for your edit. I thought I’d let you know that I have removed the SQL tags, as I was after a more generic solution, which might apply to any coding environment. My immediate need is for a database, but I was also interested in general.

Comment: @Manngo your formula is wrong - you either multiply by sqrt(12/n) or divide by sqrt(n/12). Either way `n` must be in denominator for a simple reason - you increase number of samples means you have more variance, to compensate and make it back to 1 you have to divide by some function of `n`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Oops. Thanks again.

Comment: @Manngo take a look at update

Comment: And also take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule , it is handy to know how many events you would miss for the sum of 6 (mu+-3sigma) and for the sum of 12 (mu+-6sigma, one in about half of a trillion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I have been able to read, according to the Central Limit Theorem, I should be able to approximate normally distributed random numbers by adding random numbers together.

That is a correct approach. The only problem is to carefully analyze the tails you're missing.

Let's consider making `N(0,1)` - gaussian distributed with mean 0 and std.deviation of 1. Then any other gaussian `N(\mu, \sigma)` is just scale and shift from `N(0,1)`.

So, proposed algorithm for `G(0,1)` (which is an approximation for `N(0,1)`) is

```
G(0,1) = U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1)
```

where `U(0,1)` is [uniformly distributed random number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) in the [0,1) range. Lets take a look at the mean.

```
E(G(0,1)) = 6*E(U(1,0)) = 6*0.5 = 3
```

which is exactly what you've got. So, to get 0 mean for `G(0,1)` we have to subtract 3. Lets now check the variance of the G(0,1), we have to make it equal to 1.

```
V(G(0,1)) = 6*V(U(1,0)) = 6*(1/12) = 1/2
```

Std.deviation (σ) is square root of variance, so to get it to 1 you have to divide by sqrt(1/2).

So, final expression would be

```
G(0,1) = (U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) + U(0,1) - 3)/sqrt(1/2)
```

and it is reasonably good approximation of the `N(0,1)`.

> I have no idea why sqrt(2) is involved …

Dividing by sqrt(1/2) is the same as multiplying by sqrt(2) - now I hope you know where it came from.

Some simple corollary - for some other `n` sum of U(0,1) variance multiplier will include term sqrt(n/12).

Another simple corollary - because V(U(0,1)) is equal to 1/12, then summing twelve U(0,1) will not require any multipliers

```
G(0,1) = Sum_1^12 U(0,1) - 6
```

is actually often cited in some old sampling recipes books/papers.

You might also want to take a look at related [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) and [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution)

UPDATE

I've thought about some simplification of the approach. Suppose we want to sum even number of `U(0,1)`, so `n=2m`. Again, talking about `G(0,1)` as an approximation for `N(0,1)`

```
G(0,1) = (Sum_1^2m U(0,1) - m ) / sqrt(m/6)
```

Let's rewrite it as

```
G(0,1) = (Sum_1^m U(0,1) - (m - Sum_1^m U(0,1)))/sqrt(m/6) =
       = (Sum_1^m U(0,1) - Sum_1^m(1 - U(0,1)))/sqrt(m/6)
```

Due to the fact, that `1 - U(0,1)` has the same distribution as `U(0,1)` we could
write `G(0,1)` in symmetric form

```
G(0,1) = (Sum_1^m U(0,1) - Sum_1^m U(0,1))/sqrt(m/6) =
       = Sum_1^m (U(0,1) - U(0,1)) / sqrt(m/6)
```

Comment: There's a reason the references are ***old***.  This is considered a very bad idea, both less exact and more expensive than many other algorithms.  I think it's inappropriate to call it "a correct approach".

Comment: @pjs not sure sampling as sum of 12 is very bad idea. It means we're loosing events beyond +-6sigma, which are about 1 chance in half of a trillion. Sum of 6 might be questionable, I agree

Comment: I agree that 12 is substantially better than 6.  However, it's also more expensive than exact methods.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I agree that some other methods are more accurate, but, as I mentioned, it’s not mission critical, and I was after an understanding of this approach.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have just understood the missing component. I did not know that the variance of a uniform distribution is `1/12` (I do now, dusting off some long neglected calculus). So `sqrt(2)` is not of itself  the appropriate value, but it was a coincidence that I had six values. I will post a completed formula shortly.

Comment: The difference of two U(0,1)'s is a symmetric triangle(-1,1,0) [params = min, max, mode].  That saves you the operation of subtracting off the mean, and is distributionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python, you can use the `[numpy][1]` library

```
import numpy
numpy.random.randn()
```

Comment: Sorry … ? numpy ?

Answer (score 0):

Summing random numbers provides a distribution with maximum value twice the mean, so that limits the approach severely.  Seems unable properly to approximate a normal distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Standard deviation is defined as follows:

[image: standard deviation]

where you iterate over `N` values, which are represented as `xi`, and use the mean value (`xbar`). Some JavaScript pseudocode would look like:

```
var values = [...];
for(var i = 0, var mean; i < values.length; i++) {
   mean += values[i];
}
mean /= values.length;
for(var i = 0, var standardDev; i < values.length) {
   standardDev += Math.pow(values[i] - mean, 2);
}
standardDev = Math.sqrt(standardDev / (values.length - 1));
```

Theoretically, a good RNG should deviate in a very flat manner, indicating an equal possibility across all values on the RNG's range.