# I need Half Gauss Bell in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers, gaussian

I have created a function that returns a Gaussian number between the minimum and the maximum that you put. The random subfunction gives a Gaussian number between 0 and 1, usually 0.5. I want to know if there is any way that the number tends to be 0. As if it were half gauss bell

```
function gaussianNumber(min, max, strength) {

function random(){
    var rand = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < strength; i++) {
        rand += Math.random();
    }
    return rand / strength;
}

return Math.floor(random()*(max+1-min)+min);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This might be reasonable approach to generate gaussian random number applying Central Limit Theorem, but you got your expression for `random()` wrong. If you want `G(0,1)` as approximation for gaussian `N(0,1)` with mean 0 and std.dev 1 you have to use following expression:

```
G(0,1) = (Sum_1^n U(0,1) - n/2) / sqrt(n/12)
```

Recommended `n` starts with 12, though you could experiment with fewer samples

Code

```
function G(n) {
    var rand = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        rand += Math.random();
    }
    return (rand - 0.5*n) / Math.sqrt(n/12.0);
}
```

Further discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418090/approximating-normal-distribution-by-adding-random-numbers/). You could make half of the gaussian bell from this function by just using absolute value of the function.

It is a bit unclear what do you mean wrt gaussian between min and max. Where do you want mean value of your gaussian to be? You could put mean anywhere between min and max and it is still technically in.